# weird encodings output with the same string length

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I found some tricky place and couldn't understand how does this exactly happen.

Why string which contains one character can return different byte arrays?

**Code:**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        char ch;
        ch = 0x0001;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(("" + ch).getBytes("UTF-8")));
        ch = 0x0111;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(("" + ch).getBytes("UTF-8")));
        ch = 0x1111;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(("" + ch).getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

Output will be next:

> [1]
>   [-60, -111]
>   [-31, -124, -111]

**Why exactly this happen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how UTF-8 works. Codepoints between 0 and 127 are encoded as single-byte values (to maintain ASCII compatibility); codepoints above that are encoded as two- to six-byte values.

[image: Wikipedia screenshot]

Screenshot taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

So, for your examples:

1. `0x0001` (`0b00000001`) is encoded as
   (bin) `00000001` = (dec) `1`
2. `0x0111` (`0b00000001 00010001`) is encoded as
   (bin) `11000100 10010001` = (dec) `-60 -111`
3. `0x1111` (`0b00010001 00010001`) is encoded as
   (bin) `11100001 11100001 10010001` = (dec) `-31 -124 -111`